# Benchmark the throughput of digital signatures primitives?

Tags: security, encryption, hash, cryptography, sign

Is it meaningful to benchmark the throughput of digital signature primitives?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually their performance is very well understood since they are mathematically well defined. DSA has a very good performance for signing (with default values) while RSA would have a way lower throughput but it can also be used for encryption not just for digital signing.